# Titanium Android truncates XHR XML response

Tags: android, xml, titanium

I'm refactoring an app from iOs to Android with Titanium Appecelerator (SDK version: 3.3.0.GA, IDE version:3.2.0.201312191547).
When it comes to consume an XML XHR response, Android fails:

```
var memoxhrRequest = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
memoxhrRequest.onload = function() {
Ti.API.info('Elenco richieste inviate (text) = ' + this.responseText);
memoxhrRequest = null;
var xml = Ti.XML.parseString(this.responseText.trim());
elementi = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("text").item(0).getElementsByTagName("requestlist").item(0).getElementsByTagName("request");
    Ti.API.info('elementi.item.length : ' + elementi.item.length);
```

'elementi' is the number of XML nodes inside the response.
While in iPhone everythhing's fine, in Android the response gets truncated, ending in a non valid XML document.

I tried to increase the threadSpace as in this wiki entry:
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134980/android-truncating-xhr-response
, but nothing's happened.

Any of you has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
var xml =Ti.XML.parseString(this.responseText.trim());
```

to:

```
var xml = this.responseXML;
```

Solved this issue.

Titanium happens to be much less tollerant when developing for Android rather than fo iOS...